# Computer Restart after Motherboard Splash Screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, sleep

I'm using Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot System, and in Windows 7, I switched my Computer to the Sleep Mode. How ever I forgot that I was in Sleep mode and Switched off the Power to the Computer. So when I Switched On the Machine later, selecting Windows 7 at the Boot Screen it asked me to select whether to Re-Start Computer after Deleting Re-Store point as Usual.
So I select that Option and it get Re-Started, But it Stopped at the Motherboard Splash Screen for a Moment and get re-started again and again. So I turned Off the Power to the Computer and later tried to Switch On. Problem Continues. Computer Restart after Mother Board Splash Screen.
So any Suggestion to Solve this thing is Welcome. ^_^

Comment: Try unplugging the BIOS battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting Your Computer with Windows 7 DVD or a Flash Drive, Then at the first window You see click Repair and Select Startup Recovery Options, This will Clear all those faults at the Startup.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a USB flash drive with Ubuntu and delete the Windows C:\hiberfil.sys, which should force windows to do a full reboot. See http://support.microsoft.com/KB/907477 and http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/when-power-saving-fails-fixing-windows-7-hibernation-issues/.

BTW, after getting Windows 7 working, [**check the disk for errors**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2641432) [Explorer | right-click on C: drive | Properties| Tools | Error Checking]. Ubuntu may not treat the Windows partition exactly as Windows expects, so Windows needs to "have the last word".

Comment: Thanks, yep, it was a Problem at the Startup... Startup Recovery Options in the Windows 7 OS Package Solved it.